# what will be the effect of explicitly deleting session cookie?

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies

I use php session to maintain a user's session. Session is created after he logs in and destroyed after he logs out, or the session times out. I need an option in the admin panel to log any user out forcefully, If he is active on the website. How can I accomplish this ?
I was thinking about deleting the temporary session file, which should effectively destroy the  user's session, is my theory right ?

EDIT: I also considered maintaining a record of active users in a database, and deleting a user's entry from that database would log out the user, since each page he visits would query that database to see if his entry was still present, if not, his session would be destroyed. Will that degrade the performance considerably, because of having to query the database on visiting everypage ?

Comment: You can craete a table named `onlines` in database and then when user logs into the system you add it's username to this table. after that in the administrator panel you will delete the recore belongs to the user and when the user tries to load the pages you check that if the record exsits or not. Also you should delete the record on logout.

Comment: that's exactly what I thought of doing ! will that degrade the performance of my site by a noticeably ?

Comment: I don't think ... That is the best way I know.

Comment: You invited me from the Laravel tag, so I want to ask a side question. Is there a reason you're not using http://laravel.com/docs/security ?

Comment: Had not looked into laravel when I was given this problem, is there anything there which will help me implement this particular functionality, going through the doc now.

Comment: I need to force logout the user from the admin panel