# why does deleted record still get returned using eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to laravel, and this is the first framework I'm learning in any language, anyway,
I deleted some records using :

```
public function getForceLogOut() 
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $e = $input['email'];

    echo $e;

    DB::select(DB::raw("DELETE FROM active_users WHERE email = '$e'"));
}
```

But the query executed through the eloquent model returns the object anyway, even though it has been actually been deleted (checked the table in phpMyAdmin)

```
public static function isLoggedIn()
{
    $email = Auth::user()->email;

    //$user = ActiveUser::where("email",$email); <== RETURNS THE OBJECT
    $user = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * fROM active_users where email = '$email'")); // <== WORKS FINE

    if ($user) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Auth::logout();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Doesn't eloquent model query the database and works on cached records or something similar?

EDIT: yes, as pointed out, it returns the `QueryBuilder` object! My mistake.

Comment: That's weird that `ActiveUser::where("email",$email);` returns you an Eloquent object. You should get a `QueryBuilder` unless you do `ActiveUser::where("email",$email)->first();` or `->get()`

Comment: is that weird ??, I'll see what get() or first() do. Would you like to see that var_dump() output ?

Comment: Yes please. I'm suspecting the object you got returned was a `QueryBuilder`, the object Laravel uses to prepare queries for you. If you do `ActiveUser::where("email", $email)->first();` only then it would try to find your record in the database and return null.

Comment: ok, let me try first()

Comment: @Unnawut post as answer please.

Comment: you were absolutely correct !, the noobish mistake wasted your time !, can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283066/what-will-be-the-effect-of-explicitly-deleting-session-cookie

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues Ah thanks for the reminder. I was expecting just clarification but it turned out to be the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
$user = ActiveUser::where("email",$email);
```

which returns you a `QueryBuilder`, QueryBuilders are used by Laravel to prepare your queries while you're constructing them through your Eloquent model.

If you want to get the result from your database, you should do:

```
$user = ActiveUser::where("email",$email)->first();
```

which should return you the query result, or `null` if the record doesn't exist.