# what is the best way to handle database querying before any page is loaded?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using **laravel 4 framework** , though I'm open to doing it the non-laravel way, if need be. Logged in users are maintained in a database 'active_users', if their record is deleted from that database, I want to call Auth::logout(). What is the best way to do it ?

These are the options I have considered :
1. As an event (not sure how to go about it)
2. Using AJAX to poll the script that queries the DB
3. Using (before) filter.
4.**Using table based sessions** <= This seems like an attractive option.

If there is a better different way to do this, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why delete them? Having a column identified as active or something like that would make much more sense, users have to log in eventually and you then store them in a session. If they're not active then you don't store them in a session. No point in checking if they exist every single time they refresh a page, the overload is not practical at all. Is it likely that they log in and become un-active before their session expires?

Comment: to force-logout them, that's what I've been told to do, even setting up a column would require database querying..

Comment: do you want to log them out if they are in the middle of doing something  (say reading a page?) or on the next time  they make a request? or both?   If both make something that checks their logged in status,  call in the before action, and also setup a timer that fires an ajax event to check their status and potentially log them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather simple. I highly assume that you got some server side execution on every page where you can handle server-side code, including session handling.

You would need AJAX if you'd be storing the users in the client with something like [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) but I assume you're only handling the user session on the server.

Just make a function that returns a `bool` value `true` if the user exists, `false` otherwise. If the function returns false then you simply destroy the user's session with something like [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

The function could either count the number of rows fetched when you `SELECT` rows matching the current user, if it returns 0 then you know that the row has been deleted (or it never existed in the first place, it doesn't matter). It would make more sense to add an `active` column to the row, which you can update to 0 instead of 1 if you wish to deactivate the user, that way the history is maintained. So you'd be selecting WHERE the user is active, i.e. 1, (0 rows returned if it's been changed to 0).

Do this before you check if users are allowed to see certain parts of your website, this way they will be handled just like non-logged in users.

**Edit** The solution depends on how strict the requirements are, if users must be logged out during an activity performed by the user then you need to check if the user is still active every single time you perform some activity, if that activity is client-side then you need to use AJAX to check if the user is still allowed to do what he's about to do. If the user was given permission to log-in in the first place then this is probably an overload but that's not mine to tell.

***Edit***

It doesn't matter what framework you're using, but okay, you're using Laravel. I know you can use the `Auth::logout()` function, then use it! :)

```
function userIsActive(){...}
$active = userIsActive();
if(!$active)
{
    Auth::logout();
}
```

No AJAX is needed UNLESS you want do do a JavaScript activity, if users can perform JavaScript activity that requires logged-in permissions THEN and ONLY then you need to use AJAX to check if they're still active.

Using AJAX only is not good if it's a matter of security and authendication, if the user turns off JavaScript (or has it disabled for some reason, perhaps unknown to the user) then you're pretty much ... I'm not going to finish that sentence :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically you are recommending the AJAX way, alright, have already written a script for that, but I want to know if there are better ways, as per my question, I should edit it to say I'm using laravel, a framework, It might allow a different, maybe better solution.

Comment: Not really in general but yes if client side execution must be validated aswell, please check my second edit.

Comment: I understand completely. My employer(I'm on an internship) has unreasonable requirements sometimes, as far as I know, no javascript activity needs to be done, maybe in the future, but not as of now. He did say that he wants the user to know almost immediately that he has been logged out, now that will require polling by AJAX, as far as I know; But say, I don't use ajax, I have trouble deciding where to put these checks.

Comment: If I'm not using AJAX, before every page loads ? ok, but as what ? an even based mechanism, somewhere in the route filter ? as a function call that returns bool in to an if condition in every route ?. The funny thing is, I'm not sure if this functionality is actually required by the project or not.

Comment: If that's what you want then yes, you must check it in every route (of course by calling a unique function handleUserSession() or something like that, to avoid code duplication. I've used routes in nodejs, there I simply checked if user is logged in then render the current view, otherwise render the home page (you can even store a message in a session and echo the session on the homa page, something like "Sorry but you've been logged out."). Do what works for you and is simple, you could be solving other problems by now :)

Comment: I agree, thanks, I'm going to keep this question open for a bit to see if anything else comes up !, by the way, what do you think about table based sessions, though I don't know if laravel's table driver for sessions serializes them or not.I would appreciate it if you could look into : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283066/what-will-be-the-effect-of-explicitly-deleting-session-cookie.
I'm not really stuck on this problem, I'm just trying to improve my skills and the site, that's why I'm trying to find the best way to do it, but i guess i should try these 'hacks' before asking questions.